# LINQ Or operator

Tags: linq

Is there an OR operator in LINQ?

example:

```
(controller.Equals("firm").Equals("service").Equals("training"))
```

how would i make it so that it will match 'firm' OR 'service' OR 'training'?
thanks

Comment: Some people are unaware that LINQ is, essentially, just a set of extensions to C#.NET.  Many(like me) are introduced to LINQ because of asp.net mvc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simplest way of doing what you want is likely to be to use a collection of "allowed" words and `Contains`:

```
HashSet<string> words = new HashSet<string> { "firm", "service", "training" };

var query = from controller in foo.Controllers
            where words.Contains(controller)
            select controller;
```

Or you *can* just use:

```
controller == "firm" || controller == "service" || controller == "training"
```

in the query.

If this doesn't help, please give us more context - you've only given us one non-compiling expression, rather than a clear idea of what the query is on or what it's meant to do (and indeed whether it's in LINQ to Objects, LINQ to SQL or something else).

Answer (score 3):

Using `Contains()` achieves the same effect.

```
(new[] { "firm", "service", "training" }.Contains(controller))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to dynamically build LINQ queries, you could have a look at [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx)